# How to achieve of pdf file convert to excel file format by programmatically via adobe(acrobat)?

Tags: api, pdf, adobe, restful-url, adobe-reader

How to achieve of pdf file convert to excel file format by programmatically via adobe(acrobat) ?

Creating desktop application for pdf file convert to excel file format by programmatically via adobe(acrobat) but still i'm not finding any code for convert pdf to excel via adobe(acrobat).

Have acrobat(adobe) provided that functionality or not?

Answer (score 0):

I understand you are looking at how to convert a PDF to an Microsoft Excel format using Adobe Acrobat. If I may offer a paid alternative solution to using Adobe in your program, you could look at the DocumentConverter Class that is offered by the LEADTOOLS SDK. Please see the below code snippet.

https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/v21/dh/doxc/documentconverter.html

```
using (DocumentConverter documentConverter = new DocumentConverter()) 
   { 
      var inFile = Path.Combine(ImagesPath.Path, @"Leadtools.docx"); 
      var outFile = Path.Combine(ImagesPath.Path, @"output.pdf"); 
      var format = DocumentFormat.Pdf; 
      var jobData = DocumentConverterJobs.CreateJobData(inFile, outFile, format); 
      jobData.JobName = "conversion job"; 
 
      var documentWriter = new DocumentWriter(); 
      documentConverter.SetDocumentWriterInstance(documentWriter); 
 
      var renderingEngine = new AnnWinFormsRenderingEngine(); 
      documentConverter.SetAnnRenderingEngineInstance(renderingEngine); 
 
      var job = documentConverter.Jobs.CreateJob(jobData); 
      documentConverter.Jobs.RunJob(job); 
 
      if (job.Status == DocumentConverterJobStatus.Success) 
      { 
         Console.WriteLine("Success"); 
      } 
      else 
      { 
         Console.WriteLine("{0} Errors", job.Status); 
         foreach (var error in job.Errors) 
         { 
            Console.WriteLine("  {0} at {1}: {2}", error.Operation, error.InputDocumentPageNumber, error.Error.Message); 
         } 
      } 
   }
```